# Links from my website don't appear on social websites. 'og:type' property is required, but not present

Tags: php, facebook

i got a problem with my website (http://it.com.md/). The problem is that the website and all it's posts don't appear on the social websites. Facebook just doesn't embed the information (text and images) from the website when i want to share the link.

Tried to put the facebook id and debug the link, and it always shows this:

Bad Response Code URL returned a bad HTTP response code.
The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.
The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Tried to stop the W3 Total Cache, installed the WP Facebook Open Graph protocol, but nothing works. Links that one month ago were good, now facebook doesn't see them.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: what happens when you do fetch new scraping data?

Comment: when i do fetch new scraping data it says: ”Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.„

Comment: since you have set og:type to website, it expects the following: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/website/